# How to create timed tasks in asp.net core website

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a web application, asp.net core.  It is hosted at a third party hosting service so I have little control over the IIS settings (app pool, etc.).  In fact, I only have one app pool in my contract.

I need to add timed services to the app so it will wake up every hour or so, check things and send emails when needed.  It would seem that if I use the timer, that when the app pool recycles, the timer wouldn't restart.  So it would require someone to access the site to get things running again.

I could write a service to ping the site periodically to keep it alive but am wondering if there would be a better way.  Since I am running in a hosted environment I have very limited (or no) access to the server itself.

What would be the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core, background tasks can be implemented as hosted services.

[**Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Here is the blog about how to [Run and manage periodic background tasks in ASP.NET Core 6 with C#](https://medium.com/medialesson/run-and-manage-periodic-background-tasks-in-asp-net-core-6-with-c-578a31f4b7a3)

**Test Result**

[image]

**Sample Code**

I am using asp.net core signalr and send the message to all clients.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using SignalRMiddleawre.Hubs;

namespace BackgroundService
{
    public class TimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
    {
        private int executionCount = 0;
        private readonly ILogger<TimedHostedService> _logger;
        private readonly IHubContext<MainHub> _hubcontext;
        private Timer? _timer = null;

        public TimedHostedService(IHubContext<MainHub> hubcontext, ILogger<TimedHostedService> logger)
        {
            _hubcontext = hubcontext;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public  Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service running.");
            _hubcontext.Clients.All.SendAsync("Chat_ReceiveMessage", "[System - Background Service ]", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + " " + "Timed Hosted Service running.");
            _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero,
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private void DoWork(object? state)
        {
            var count = Interlocked.Increment(ref executionCount);

            _logger.LogInformation(
                "Timed Hosted Service is working. Count: {Count}", count);
            _hubcontext.Clients.All.SendAsync("Chat_ReceiveMessage", "[System - Background Service ]", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + " " + "DoSomethingAsync method triggered.  Count: "+count+"");
        }

        public  Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service is stopping.");
             _hubcontext.Clients.All.SendAsync("Chat_ReceiveMessage", "[System - Background Service ]", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + " " + "Timed Hosted Service is stopping.");

            _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _timer?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**Register it in Program.cs file.**

[image]